# Is a *by-law* the same thing as an *in-law*?

Tags: meaning, synonyms, kinship-terms

When I was a student (over fifty years ago) I had a landlady who used to talk about her 'aunt-by-law'. I wish I had been bold enough to ask her the nature of the relationship, but I have always assumed it was either her husband's aunt, or the wife of one of her parent's brothers.

Has anyone else ever heard the term *by-law*, used and is it synonymous with *in-law*?

Comment: I have never heard the expression, and I can't find it in the OED.

Comment: I found an [excerpt](http://books.google.it/books?id=gQ7iAAAAMAAJ&q=%22uncle+by+law%22&dq=%22uncle+by+law%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7WOmU7KaFKuy7AbwyoGQDA&redir_esc=y) which cites *unle-by-law*, *aunt-by-law* and explains the relationship!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well done! It took an Italian scholar and it seems an Italian search to find it! I will now adopt Italy as my team to win the World Cup!

Comment: An aunt by-law is a by-law issued by a country club forbidding you to let your aunt onto the golf course.

Comment: @BlessedGeek But that is only because you missed the hyphen after 'aunt'.

Answer (score 4):

An *aunt-**by**-law* would be the wife of one of one’s parents’ siblings.  You share no blood with that woman, but she has married your uncle.

I suppose you **could** call her an *aunt-**in**-law*, but that sounds rather odd. Normally one’s *in-laws* are those new family members created by one’s own marriage, not someone else’s.

We never made a distinction between by-blood and by-law uncles and aunts growing up, although of course you were always aware of it.

Then there’s the old phenomenon of an *uncle-by-courtesy*, which is something else again. Now it’s simply an honorific for someone older than you whom you would not address by their first name, but who is a family friend, likely of your parents’.

Comment: *Aunt or uncle-by-marriage* I think would be the usual term. But only this one individual do I ever remember saying *aunt-by-law*. I do think it sounds more inclusive to leave out the *in-law* or *by-law* altogether, particularly as regards nieces and nephews. Some people will refer to 'my husband's niece' or 'my wife's nephew'. As one who is an only child with a wife who was one of five, I am always glad to call my wife's many nieces and nephews as though they were my own, especially since I am not blessed with any myself.

Comment: I disagree that "normally one's in-laws are those new family members created by one's own marriage, not someone else's". It is quite usual to refer to your sister's husband or brother's wife as your *brother-in-law*, or *sister-in-law*.